# PHP header location - not displaying error?

Tags: wamp, php, wampserver

When I `echo` something before `header("LOCATION: page.php");` - I expect to show an error but it didnt, it just redirect to that page. What gone wrong?

**Example:**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
echo "Hello";
header("LOCATION: page.php");
?>
```

**In the php.ini**

```
output_buffering = off
error_reporting =  E_ALL
display_errors = on
```

I am using Wamp, PHP 5.3.0

Comment: Is this the *exact* code you use?

Comment: is there an output buffering started?

Comment: Have you tried adding `flush()` before header? Or `ob_end_flush()`? Is this example or exact file that you tried and it is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var_dump(ini_get('output_buffering'));
```

and what about this one

```
var_dump(ob_get_status(1));
```

?

Comment: `array
  0 => 
    array
      'chunk_size' => int 0
      'size' => int 40960
      'block_size' => int 10240
      'type' => int 1
      'status' => int 0
      'name' => string 'default output handler' (length=22)
      'del' => boolean true`

Comment: When I add `ob_end_flush()` before the `echo` it seem to fix the problem... but why?! I did not include `ob_start()` anywhere

Comment: in fact, your `output_buffering` is set to `40960` value. The only you need is to find - where. are you sure you are running `var_dump(ini_get('output_buffering'));` in this very file?