# Codeigniter redirect in case of error on localhost

Tags: php, codeigniter, wamp

I have installed wamp server on localhost. And created application using codeigniter framework.

I am using `redirect(url)` method in controller. If any error found in same controller, page redirects to that url. But on server it does not redirect and showing error. 
Same functionality I want on localhost.

How to achieve it?

```
controller Appointments extends CI_COntroller
{
   function index()
    {
        load view
    }
    function save()
    {
         $customer_id=$c_id; //accessing undeclared variable $c_id which is error
         redirect(base_url("appointments"))

    }
}
```

in above code error as been occured at $customer_id=$c_id; so rediection should be prevented and error should be shown. error shows when files are on server but not showing error on localhost.

Comment: what error it is showing?

Comment: it does not display any error any redirect. i want to prevent redirect in case of error found and display eror

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code snippet.

Comment: Well, your remote server is obviously set up different than your WAMP server. If you want to see error just comment out the redirect. I do not understand what you are having trouble with. Or if you want to prevent error because variable is undeclared test if it exists...

IMO you should code in such way, that you have 0 (at least PHP) errors.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I get you right, but in case if you want to show a error after the redirection you should store it as flash data in session and show it on the page where you redirect to.

Answer (score 0):

i got answer

set `output_buffering = off in php.ini` file

refere link [PHP header location - not displaying error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093719/php-header-location-not-displaying-error)